# How to trace with SQL Server profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

i am trying my hands on SQL server profiler i would like to know how to trace using SQL server profiler. any link with apprpiate GUI will be more then helpfull.

Comment: Just run it? And if it has only Blank template, then add there T-SQL Batch Completed event, this way you see something either.

Comment: Study the [Mastering SQL Server Profiler](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Video/66676/) video course - highly educational! With that, you'll know all you need to know about how to use SQL Profiler

Answer (score 14):

Steps:

**SQL Server Management Studio**

1. Go to MS SQL Server Management Studio and select the database you want to trace in the Profiler.
2. Right click the database and select New Query.
3. In the query window type select db_id() then execute... and remember the number generated

**SQL Server Profiler**

1. File - New Trace then choose server, Authentication Mode provide UserName and Password and click connect.
2. In the trace properties go to events selection tab.
3. click **Show all events** and **Show all columns**.
4. Click *Column Filters* button
5. click DatabaseID
6. click Equals then input the DB ID generated before in the Mangement Studio
7. Click Ok then click the **Run** Button

Answer (score 4):

In sql Profiler go to File -> New Trace Enter your server name

[image: SQL Profiler]

In the next windows just click run and u ll see the trace commands
[image: Trace]

Execute few statements in your management studio and then check the profiler