# What queries have been executed against a database and how long did they take?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a Sql Server database running in Azure, and I'm having some performance issues I'm not seeing in a similar database that is hosted locally.

Is there a way to determine what/when/how long queries were executed against these databases?

Comment: Can you post some code, how you are getting your data from your database? Do you use Depency injection...? What internet connection do you have ? Much variables...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL Server Profiler to see exactly what has been run on your SQL Server database.

Check for more information in the below thread;
[How to trace with SQL Server profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845304/how-to-trace-with-sql-server-profiler)

Running a trace in SQL Profiler is quite hard on performance, so best not to let it run for too long. It will also have an impact on the performance whatever queries you are running, so take this into account when analyzing timings.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL is pretty sensitive to number of I/O operations required to complete your query. Locally you are limited only by your disk performance, but in Azure you have some DTU limits and those limits are highly related to number of disk operations. Use "Query perfomance Insights" to find out which queries are slow and do the following:

1. Remove unnecessary columns from your select statement. Do not use `select * from` , carefully specify only required columns. Sometimes you have to change your application logic to not fetch everything.
2. Check the execution plan. In most cases system will suggest creating index for your query.
3. Create appropriate index that will be based on columns in your WHERE clause and will use INCLUDE statement to include data from other columns in your query.

For example, you need to select 5 columns and two of them are used in WHERE clause:

```
select Col1, Col2, DataCol1, DataCol2, DataCol3 from MYTABLE
where Col1=@Param1 and Col2=@Param2
```

You should create the following index:

```
create index IX_MyIndex on MYTABLE(Col1,Col2) INCLUDE(DataCol1, DataCol2, DataCol3)
```

Hope it helps.